# angularstrap typeahead with json object array is not working

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, angular-strap

I am using angularstrap typeahead directive. Its working fine with single object json values but its not working when replacing the json with my json object array.

Demo Json:

```js
typeahead= ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia"];
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="typeaheadValue" bs-typeahead="typeahead">
```

The above code is working fine.

My JSON object array:

```js
typeahead = [
    {id: 1, name: 'name1', email: 'email1@domain.com'},
    {id: 2, name: 'name2', email: 'email2@domain.com'},
    {id: 3, name: 'name3', email: 'email3@domain.com'}
];

$scope.typeaheadFn = function(query) {
   return $.map($scope.typeahead, function(contacts) {
      return contacts;
   });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="typeaheadValue" bs-typeahead="typeaheadFn">
```

Please give me some solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map your items to a list of strings, I believe.

Try:

```
$scope.typeaheadFn = function(query) {
    return $.map($scope.typeahead, function(contact) {
        return contact.name;
    });
}
```

(I should add that I am currently stumped by something similar)

Answer (score 1):

If you have, for example:

```
items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'name1', email: 'email1@domain.com'},
    {id: 2, name: 'name2', email: 'email2@domain.com'},
    {id: 3, name: 'name3', email: 'email3@domain.com'}
];
```

You will need:

```
<input type="text" bs-typeahead ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items|orederBy:'name'|filter:{name:$viewValue}:optionalCompareFn"></input>
```

If you exclude filter from ng-options matching will be done on every property of item object, so if you want it to be done on one property add `filter:{propName:$viewValue}`. Also, if you exclude `optionalCompareFn`, default comparison from angular will be applied, but you can add your custom one (on your `$scope`), with signature (`actual` is property value of the item, stated in filter, not the whole object).

```
optionalCompareFn(expected,actual){ return /compare and return true or false/}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Attempt 1

I finally got this semi-working after a huge amount of frustration.

An easy way to get your desired text appearing is for each item to have a `toString` method.

You might have something like

```js
typeaheadData = [
  {id: 1, text: "abc", toString: function() { return "abc"; }},
  {id: 2, text: "def", toString: function() { return "def"; }}
]
```

Then you will see the correct text in the options that popup, but the matching won't yet work properly (the items shown by the widget won't match the text the user enters in the box).

To get this working I used the new `filter` option that's been added in the current git version of `angular-strap`. Note that it's not even in the pre-built `dist/angular-strap.js` file in the repository, you will need to rebuild this file yourself to get the new feature. (As of commit ce4bb9de6e53cda77529bec24b76441aeaebcae6).

If your `bs-typeahead` widget looks like this:

```html
<input bs-typeahead ng-options="item for item in items" filter="myFilter" ng-model="myModel" />
```

Then the filter `myFilter` is called whenever the user enters a key. It's called with two arguments, the first being the entire list you passed to the `typeahead`, and the second being the text entered. You can then loop over the list and return the items you want, probably by checking whether the text matches one or more of the properties of an item. So you might define the filter like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap'])
  .filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(items, text) {
      var a = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        // Match an item if the entered text matches its `text` property.
        if (item.label.indexOf(text) >= 0) {
          a.push(item);
        }
      });
      return a;
    };
  });
```

Unfortunately this still isn't quite right; if you select an item by clicking on it, then the text parameter will be the actual object from the items list, not the text.

## Attempt 2

I still found this too annoying so I made a fork of `angular-strap` (https://github.com/amagee/angular-strap) which lets you do this:

```js
typeaheadData = [
  {id: 1, text: "abc"},
  {id: 2, text: "def"}
]

//...

$scope.myFormatter = function(id) {
   if (id == null) { return; }
   typeaheadData.forEach(function(d) { 
       if (d.id === id) { 
           return d.text; 
       }
   });
};
```

```html
<input bs-typeahead ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="myModel" 
  key-field="id" text-field="text" formatter="myFormatter" />
```

With no need to fuss around with `toString` methods or filters. The `text-field` is what the user sees, and the `key-field` is what is written to the model.

<del>(Nope! Still doesn't work if you update the model without going through the view).</del>

The `formatter` option is needed so when you set the model value to just the key field, the  widget can figure out the right text to display.

Comment: key-field="id" text-field="text" this is not working. If you are sure then make fiddlw for it.